# Log out all user with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise in my ruby-on-rails app. I have a User class and an AdminUser class using devise. In my admin panel I would like to logout all Users but not AdminUsers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the scope-level sign out methods.  So, if you want to sign out all users (User class), then you would do this.

```
sign_out :user
```

Comment: better to leave more descriptive answers than not...two cents

Answer (score 15):

**Very late**, but the answer could be something like this

```
for user in User.all
  sign_out user
end
```

Answer (score 4):

As someone said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406208/how-can-i-reset-all-devise-sessions-so-every-user-has-to-login-again), the simplest way to do this is to change the rails secret token.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for posting it here; even though it doesn't actually answer the question, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

```
@users = User.all
@users.log_out
```

and

```
def log_out
  # depending on how you store the user's token, just delete it from the database
end
```

Assuming you are using database authentication.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using devise :database_authenticatable. I don't see what needs to be deleted.

Comment: Try to run on all the users with destroy_user_session_path(user).