# How to clear all devise sessions?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Someone else asked this question while back here is the question

[How can I reset all devise sessions so every user has to login again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406208/how-can-i-reset-all-devise-sessions-so-every-user-has-to-login-again)

and the answer is this:

`rake db:sessions:clear`

However When I do it I get this error:
`Don't know how to build task 'db:session:clear'`

I tried doing this as well

`~ $ heroku run bash`

and then

`~ $ rake db:sessions:clear`

Still same error.

Any suggestions ?

tried these as well, still not working:
`~ $ heroku run rake db:sessions:clear`

Comment: Are you storing your sessions in the database? If not, you should try `rake tmp:sessions:clear`.

Comment: This didn't work either. I was wondering why it's not able to build the task

Comment: any error while running `rake tmp:sessions:clear`

Comment: @Viren No errors for that, it's just that the session still there even after that command.

Comment: @Observer Stupid question but after clear did you restarted your server .

Comment: @Viren it's so strange! I tried! Still there! I've tried a new rails app and rvm setup, but I still get the same error

Comment: did you try ```/users/sign_out``` request to delete it. But need to config the method :get for sign_out action in config/initializer/devise.rb

Answer (score 0):

If you are using session using client side cookies, you can simply restart your server as session ids are stored in memory in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def index
    reset_session
  end
```