# Kill User Sessions on Devise / Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm searching and trying for hours now, but I can't find a solution.

I need a way to kill all User Sessions so they have to log in again. I looked at the SO Answers, but somehow nothing wants to work. The most popular being:

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

which throws a

> `Don't know how to build task 'db:sessions:clear'`.

What am I missing, has someone a good solution for this?

What I need basically is something like a task, or console wizardry to Kill All Sessions on Devise.

---

[Devise Session Controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L20)

[How can I reset all devise sessions so every user has to login again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406208/how-can-i-reset-all-devise-sessions-so-every-user-has-to-login-again?rq=1)

Comment: Maybe you could create a function with the devise session helper : user_session, [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), something like user_session = nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the key in **config/session_store.rb**

```
MyAppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_name_session'
```

I changed it from `_myapp_name_session` to `_myapp_name_sessions` and all users are loged out.

> reminder: Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.