# disable all logins except admin in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization

while doing admin work, i'd like to disable user logins --
is there some way to use devise for this -- I don't THINK this
is suitable for rolify -- because this is a temporary disablement --
thanks in advance for any help,
rick

Comment: Hi Rick, do you want to keep access for the admin or do you want simply every user disabled?

Comment: keep access for the admin -- i notice the turnout gem -- but that has to be run from the command line -- hoping for something like the drupal maintenance mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Back-End**

If you wanted to create a "maintenance" mode, you'll be best doing something like this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

#app/models/admin.rb
class Admin < User
   def maintainance!
     self.toggle! :maintainance
   end
end
```

This will need a `maintenance` column in the `users` table, and you'll have to add a `type` column in the `users` table, too.

You could get away with keeping this in the `User` model, however, you'd need some conditions to determine whether the user is an admin. Since you didn't specify how you're differentiating, above is how we do it.

--

You'd be able to call it like this:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
   def maintenance
      current_user.maintenance! #-> toggles so you'll just be able to call this as you need.
   end
end

#config/routes.rb
resources :settings, only: [] do
    put :maintenance #-> url.com/settings/maintenance (considering current_user present)
end
```

This will allow you to *set* the "maintenance" mode through your `user` settings area. If you don't have one, you'll be able to use the above code to get it working.

---

**Front-End**

With the backend in place, you'll be able to then manage the front-end.

To do this, you'll need a helper to determine if any user has set the "maintenance" mode...

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
class ApplicationHelper
   def maintenance_mode?
      Admin.exists? maintenance: true
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use this helper to determine whether you should allow `Devise` to accept logins or not:

```
#app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
<% unless maintenance_mode? %>
  ... devise form ...
<% end %>
```

The helper will execute a DB request, but keeping it in the `devise` areas *only* (IE it's not "site wide") should make it okay.

```
#app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   before_action :check_maintenance

   private

   def check_maintenance 
       redirect_to root_path, notice: "Sorry, maintenance mode is in effect; no logins." if maintenance_mode?
   end
end
```

This will prevent any controller-based actions from firing.

Finally, if you want to get rid of any logged-in *users*, you'll need to do something quirky, like resetting the sessions or something similar:

- [How can I reset all devise sessions so every user has to login again?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406208/how-can-i-reset-all-devise-sessions-so-every-user-has-to-login-again)
- [Devise force signout](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/xs4FhWGoq7M)

Comment: thanks!  I'll give this a try on Monday -- i have already created an 'admin' flag on users to indicate whether they have admin permissions -- this all looks good. thanks!

Comment: This worked -- I was getting a circular dependency though for SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController so i renamed that MaintSessionsController, put it in the controllers directory, not controllers/devise, and put this into config.rb: devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "registrations", sessions: "maint_sessions" }

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do:

**1. Create a method for your User model.** It could be something like `active`, or `able_to_login`.

**2. Set this attribute to `:boolean`.**

**3. Use `rails console`.** Use the console to set the active method to `true` or `false`, enabling or disabling your users to access your application:

```
user = User.all
   user.each do |u|
     u.active = false # or
     u.able_to_login = false
     u.save
   end
```

I don't think this is the best method, but it should work without installing another gem or heavy code.

Comment: i'd like to keep admin access -- would this do that?

Comment: and, I'm okay with adding another Gem -- this is a feature that I want to add, not just a one time event. Thanks!

Comment: that is helpful, just not quite what I was looking for .. but it gives me ideas.

Comment: Yes, for admin access, you can create another boolean method, like `user.admin? # true`. Consider upvoting or making it the right answer, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

In your /models/user.rb add this method

```
def active_for_authentication? 
  super && is_admin?
end

def is_admin?
  # returns true if user is admin
end
```

This is the "Devise way" of doing this :)

Comment: I'm not sure why people recommend putting this feature on the user object.  I created a maintenance object -- only editable by the admin user -- before logging check for existence of a maintenance object -- and not allow if it exists.